# Cannot compile Qt program for use on ARM device

Tags: c++, qt, arm, cross-compiling

I want to compile a Qt program for an ARM device.

I installed the toolchain for ARM and here is how my qmake.conf file looks like:

```
#
# qmake configuration for building with arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++
#

include(../../common/linux.conf)
include(../../common/gcc-base-unix.conf)
include(../../common/g++-unix.conf)
include(../../common/qws.conf)

# modifications to g++.conf
QMAKE_CC                = arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc
QMAKE_CXX               = arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
QMAKE_LINK              = arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
QMAKE_LINK_SHLIB        = arm-linux-gnueabi-g++
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -O3 -march=armv5te
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O3 -march=armv5te
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT = /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT = /usr/share/qt4/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT = /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib


# modifications to linux.conf
QMAKE_AR                = arm-linux-gnueabi-ar cqs
QMAKE_OBJCOPY           = arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
QMAKE_STRIP             = arm-linux-gnueabi-strip

load(qt_config)
```

The problem is that if I include (as shown above):

```
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT = /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT = /usr/share/qt4/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT = /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib
```

I get an error that says :

```
main.cpp:1:30: fatal error: QtGui/QApplication: No such file or directory
```

And if I exclude :

```
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT = /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT = /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib
```

I get an error that says :

```
/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qatomic_x86_64.h:133:29: error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’
```

I am new to this and have been struggling for over 40 hours this week and can't find what's the problem.

I can compile a simple c++ program for the ARM device, but when I try to use Qt I get the above errors so I think that the problem is in 1 case that the Qt headers are not loaded and in the other that the wrong converter file from c++ to asm is used.

Comment: Why don't you use the existing specs? Is it some specific ARM not yet supported by Qt proper? Have you tried `qmake -spec linux-arm-gnueabi-g++` without your custom ARM setup?

Comment: Thank for the reply. It is nothing too fancy, but that's the way I found that I should do the compiling so that's how I have done.

Comment: Try to drop your work, and use the builtin qmake mkspecs support for it. Let me know the result of this trial.

Comment: Well the above pasted qmake.conf is from `qt4/mkspecs/qws/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++` in which I added `QMAKE_CFLAGS += -O3 -march=armv5te
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -O3 -march=armv5te
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT = /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/include
QMAKE_INCDIR_QT = /usr/share/qt4/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR_QT = /opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.5.1/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib` because I was confused why the x86_64 header is used. If I remove the above rows and let it be like it was when installed I get `/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qatomic_x86_64.h:133:29: error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’`.

Comment: qws is not what I was suggesting. I was suggesting the non-qws version! Please run `qmake -spec linux-arm-gnueabi-g++` as suggested.

Comment: After running `qmake -spec linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -o Makefile *.pro` I get the same error: `/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qatomic_x86_64.h:133:29: error: impossible constraint in ‘asm’
`.

Comment: Please paste the whole output of `qmake -spec linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ *.pro && make VERBOSE=1` to some pastebin site, and give me a link. Also, please show a minimal main.pro that can reproduce this issue, and give a link to your toolchain. I will try to reproduce it locally.

Comment: After looking more careful I found that there is no `linux-arm-gnueabi-g++` in my mkspecs folder. So I got the error because I was using the old Makefile beacause no new one was created.

Comment: Which Qt 4 exactly are you using? Surely, there is ... in the latest: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/ece0bd590a06d8d8f4f922395a8e68f7b0e678e6:mkspecs/linux-arm-gnueabi-g++

Comment: I am using 4.7.0. Do you recommend installing 4.8 ? Or can I create the folder with the specific files?

Comment: Not sure that it would fix the problem, but surely, updating would be useful. :)

Comment: I had 4.8 installed yesterday and the problem was the same. Then I tried with 4.7 thinking maybe there is a bug or something in 4.8. Also my ARM device came with an CD with 4.7 on it so I thought is better to use 4.7.

Comment: Right, so please try `qmake -r -spec linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ && make VERBOSE=1` with 4.8.

Comment: Ok, installing it now. I would come back in 1-2 hours with the output of the above command.

Comment: I still get the same error in 4.8. Link to pastebin: [link](http://pastebin.com/SY6KxZYZ). The application on which I get the error is a simple `Hello World`. What other information do you need?

Comment: Does the helloworld program compile with Qt 5.2?

Comment: I tried in 4.7 and 4.8 and it compiled, the problem is when I try to compile for ARM.

Comment: I am asking about Qt 5.2 for ARM to see if the issue is fixed there...

Comment: Sorry for the miss understanding. I installed qt 5.2, but when I use qmake it still uses the 4.8 qmake. How can I specify it to use the qmake from 5.2 ?

Comment: Either use qtchooser, or specify full path to the 5.2 qmake for this testing... or at least have that path in PATH earlier than the 4.8 installation path.

Comment: In 5.2 I get: [link](http://pastebin.com/zbtyGtSz).

Comment: What device are you trying to build for? What toolchain exactly are you trying to use? Can you give a download link to the toolchain?

Comment: It's a [tiny210 device](http://www.friendlyarm.net/products/tiny210). I can't remember exactly what toolchain I used, because in the last 3-4 days I installed/removed a lot of programs to try compiling. Anyway the toolchain should be on the above website, and if you can get it to work with any of them I will install that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to compile it, the problem was that I used the wrong options for `./configure` when installing Qt embedded. After starting from scratch it worked without problems.

The options used:
`./configure -opensource -confirm-license -no-pch -embedded arm -platform qws/linux-x86_64-g++ -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -little-endian -no-webkit`

Answer (score 2):

Just reading the message, `qatomic_x86_64.h` is rather suspicious in an ARM build. That's obviously the wrong toolchain. So, you definitely need the first statements to select the ARM toolchain.

However, I'm uncertain why your approach to fix a missing include is to remove even more include directories. Nor do I understand why you assume a Qt **library** is missing when the error is clearly on a **header** inclusion.

As far as I can see, the only problem is that `QtGui\` is a relative path, which is not found in any `QMAKE_INCDIR_QT` directory. Where is your `QtGui` include directory?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My QtGui is in /usr/share/qt4/include

Comment: @NAlex : That's probably QtGui from the `x86_64` toolchain.

Comment: Yes, probably, but I can't find another include directory in Qt. In the QtCore directory I can see multiple headers like: qatomic_arm.h , qatomic_i386.h, qatomic_x86_64.h etc. So I think they are all there, but Qt uses the wrong one.

Comment: It's not the wrong tool-chain, but that the toolchain is using the host's include path.  If you get this to compile at all, it's a recipe for odd behaviour at runtime.  You need to  add the --sysroot option to GCC to point the compiler to your target's header and library files rather than the host's.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but I was on vacation. Could you give me more details, please? Until now I only used the command line to compile for the machine I was using, and did not cross-compile.